# how to use CGAL library while programming in visual studio 10 in windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, cgal

I am new working with CGAL and need help how to use when I will start a project in Visual Studio 10 in windows 7. How can I use this CGAL libraries with my program in VS 10. Anyone's help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete tutorial [here](http://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html).